# Is it possible to implement Q_PROPERTY READ/WRITE accessors without using member functions?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

Generally, a lot of code does nothing but get/set class members. For that I implemented a simple container class to have getters and setters associated
to a "field". At a first sight this looks pretty ok and results in far less code. This is how the container class looks like:

**Member.h**

```
#include <functional>

template <class T>
class Member
{
public:
  T data;

  using Getter_t = std::function<T(void)>;
  using Setter_t = std::function<void(T)>;
  using Notify_t = std::function<void(void)>;

  Setter_t m_setterFunc;
  Getter_t m_getterFunc;
  Notify_t m_notifyFunc;

  Member()
  {
      this->m_getterFunc  = [=] (void) -> T  { return this->data; };
      this->m_setterFunc  = [=] (T data) -> void { this->data = data; };
      this->m_notifyFunc  = [] (void) -> void { };
  }

  auto get() -> T { return this->m_getterFunc(); }
  auto set(T data) -> void { this->m_setterFunc(data); this->m_notifyFunc(); }

  auto getter(Getter_t func) -> Member& { this->m_getterFunc  = func; return *this; }
  auto setter(Setter_t func) -> Member& { this->m_setterFunc  = func; return *this; }
  auto notify(Notify_t func) -> Member& { this->m_notifyFunc  = func; return *this; }

  ~Member() { }
};
```

I know some things are not perfect yet but that's okay for now. The next few lines show how `Member` instances are defined and the simple and convenient way to access underlying data. `get`, `set` and `notify` functions can be replaced by lambdas or function pointers to override custom behavior.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Member.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    Member<int> foo;
    Member<std::string> bar;

    void barChanged() { std::cout << "bar changed\n"; }
};

auto main(int argc, const char * argv[]) -> int
{
    MyClass instance;

    instance.foo.notify([] () -> void { std::cout << "foo changed\n"; });
    instance.bar.notify(std::bind(&MyClass::barChanged, instance));

    instance.foo.set(10);
    instance.bar.set("some string");

    std::cout << instance.foo.get() << " " << instance.bar.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem now is that the `Q_PROPERTY` macro expects function names for the `READ` and `WRITE` accessors and I'm back at where I started: I have to write get and set functions for each property explicitly. Exactly what I wanted to avoid.

```
class MyOtherClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool flag READ getFlag WRITE setFlag NOTIFY flagChanged);
public:
    Member<bool> m_flag;
    auto getFlag() -> bool { return m_flag.get(); }
    auto setFlag(bool flag) -> void { this->m_flag.set(flag); }
};
```

Is it possible to directly use the already existing `m_flag.get` and `m_flag.set` functions? I tried the obvious things but they were either rejected by the moc or resulted in too much code.

## Edit

As mentioned below, the `MEMBER` keyword makes it possible to have properties without specifying get and set functions. However, private members then only can be accessed by their names (`this->property("myPropertyName")`) and also there's no way to achieve more than "plain" get and set.

To make it more clear: The motivation is not to just avoid writing get and set functions but trying to implement a flexible member system which

- by default performs get/set as expected
- supports custom logic (for example forward newly set values to some other instance)
- can be used for C++ class members and is compatible with Qt properties

And the only missing piece is the bridge between the `Q_PROPERTY` `READ`/`WRITE`accessors and the get/set methods of the `Member` class.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe you should try some magic with macros? Wrap a `Q_PROPERTY` macro to another one that will create 2 methods + declares a property. I'm not sure, but it may not be compatible with MOC compiler.

Comment: Other way - is to create dynamic properties at runtime.

Comment: @SaZ I'll try to avoid macros as good as possible. But dynamic properties could be an option, I'll try that one out. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that it's possible to redirect `READ` or `WRITE` property methods to some other internal or external object without writing wrappers, but if your getters and setters do not do anything except return or set data: there is `MEMBER` variable association at least in latest Qt versions.

From [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#requirements-for-declaring-properties):

```
Q_PROPERTY(type name
           (READ getFunction [WRITE setFunction] |
            MEMBER memberName [(READ getFunction | WRITE setFunction)])
           [RESET resetFunction]
           [NOTIFY notifySignal]
           [REVISION int]
           [DESIGNABLE bool]
           [SCRIPTABLE bool]
           [STORED bool]
           [USER bool]
           [CONSTANT]
           [FINAL])
```

> A READ accessor function is required if no MEMBER variable was
>   specified. It is for reading the property value. Ideally, a const
>   function is used for this purpose, and it must return either the
>   property's type or a const reference to that type. e.g.,
>   QWidget::focus is a read-only property with READ function,
>   QWidget::hasFocus().
>
> A WRITE accessor function is optional. It is for setting the property
>   value. It must return void and must take exactly one argument, either
>   of the property's type or a pointer or reference to that type. e.g.,
>   QWidget::enabled has the WRITE function QWidget::setEnabled().
>   Read-only properties do not need WRITE functions. e.g., QWidget::focus
>   has no WRITE function.
>
> **A MEMBER variable association** is required if no READ accessor function
>   is specified. This **makes the given member variable readable and
>   writable without the need of creating READ and WRITE accessor
>   functions**. It's still possible to use READ or WRITE accessor functions
>   in addition to MEMBER variable association (but not both), if you need
>   to control the variable access.

Using `MEMBER` you do not need to write getters and setters.